# Funny-ness with titlesec and section labels ("missing \begin{document}")

Tags: errors, titlesec

Having a problem somewhat akin to ["How to put section number into the right side of section title in LaTeX"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24961/how-to-put-section-number-into-the-right-side-of-section-title-in-latex) (and neither of the two answers there floating my boat), I was tinkering with `titlesec`, and came across an error message I cannot fathom.

Ignoring good looks of the example for the sake of brevity, this works:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{\thesection}{0pt}{}{}   %% <--

\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\end{document}
```

(Yields "0.1Section".)

Switching the marked line to this also works:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{}{0pt}{\thesection}{}
```

(Yields "0.1Section".)

However, the following line does **not** work:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{}{0pt}{}{\thesection}
```

(Expected "Section0.1", but yields LaTeX Error, "Missing \begin{document}".)

Apparently the "*after*"-Field of `\titleformat` handles things differently. Why does this happen, and can it be avoided?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "after" field is optionally specified in square brackets after the "before" field, not in curly braces. This is why this fails.

The proper syntax is thus:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{}{}{0pt}{}[\thesection]
```

which yields the expected result:

> Section
>
> 0.1

Comment: /doublefacepalm...